# How can I access MinIO files on the file system?

Tags: minio

On the underlying server filesystem, MinIO seems to store the content of an uploaded file (e.g. ***X***) in a file called ***xl.meta*** in a directory bearing the original file name (e.g. ***X/xl.meta***).

However, the file ***xl.meta*** is encoded. How can I access the original file content on the server file system itself (i.e. see the text inside a plain text file or being able to play a sound file with a respective application)?

Comment: Since it is erasure.coded , it is recommended to use s3 api complaint client to read. Do not directly modify the backend.

Answer (score 2):

It would not be possible since the object you are seeing on the backend fs is not the actual object, it is only the erasure coded part(s) that is split across all the disks in a given erasure set. So, you could do it if you were just using fs mode (single node, single disk) but in erasure coded environment you will need to have quorum to be able to download the object, and that via an S3 supported method and not directly from the backend. Technically not quorum, rather n/2 if you just want to read the object, but as a rule you should avoid doing anything in the backend fs.

If you happen to want to just see the contents of xl.meta, and not recover the file itself, you can use this something like `mc support inspect myminio/test/syslog/xl.meta --export=json` (or you can build a binary from https://github.com/minio/minio/tree/master/docs/debugging/xl-meta but using `mc` is probably easier).